# Replace string in a file from a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I need help with replacing a string in a file where "from"-"to" strings coming from a given file.

**fromto.txt:**

```
"TRAVEL","TRAVEL_CHANNEL"
"TRAVEL HD","TRAVEL_HD_CHANNEL"
"FROM","TO"
```

First column is what to I'm searching for, which is to be replaced with the second column.

So far I wrote this small script:

```
while read p; do
  var1=`echo "$p" | awk -F',' '{print $1}'`

  var2=`echo "$p" | awk -F',' '{print $2}'`
  echo "$var1" "AND" "$var2"

  sed -i -e 's/$var1/$var2/g' test.txt
done <fromto.txt
```

Output looks good (x AND y), but for some reason it does not replace the first column ($var1) with the second ($var2).

**test.txt:**

```
"TRAVEL"
```

Output:

```
"TRAVEL" AND "TRAVEL_CHANNEL"
sed -i -e 's/"TRAVEL"/"TRAVEL_CHANNEL"/g' test.txt
"TRAVEL HD" AND "TRAVEL_HD_CHANNEL"
sed -i -e 's/"TRAVEL HD"/"TRAVEL_HD_CHANNEL"/g' test.txt
"FROM" AND "TO"
sed -i -e 's/"FROM"/"TO"/g' test.txt

$ cat test.txt
"TRAVEL"
```

Comment: To get you started, `sed -i` will work on a file in-place.  Now you just need to figure out the commands for `sed` :)

Comment: Yes, I can add sed command before each line, but the actual "fromto.txt" is quite big. It is somehow possible to read these variables/arguments for sed from a file?

Comment: That's a helpful clarification -- it isn't immediately obvious from the description.  So as a simple recipe (this can be done from the shell prompt): 1. for each line in the file; 2. split the line, extracting the values between the '"'; 3. use those values in a `sed` command for replacement (e.g. `sed -i 's/$val1/$val2/g'`).  Does that make sense?

Comment: You can use sed to create a sed script from the replacement file and then use that for a `sed - f` call.

Comment: This gave me some inspiration, I updated the main question. :)

Comment: Why use `awk` instead of `IFS=, read var1 var2`?

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, only double quotes.

Comment: Yes! I used single quotes in sed, I replaced with double quotes: sed -i -e "s/$var1/$var2/g" test.txt and works now, great. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

input:

```
➜  cat fromto
TRAVEL TRAVEL_CHANNEL
TRAVELHD TRAVEL_HD
➜  cat inputFile
TRAVEL
TRAVELHD
```

The work:

```
   ➜  awk 'BEGIN{while(getline < "fromto") {from[$1] = $2}} {for (key in from) {gsub(key,from[key])} print}' inputFile > output
```

and output:

```
➜  cat output
TRAVEL_CHANNEL
TRAVEL_CHANNEL_HD
➜
```

This first (`BEGIN{}`) loads your input file into an associate array:  `from["TRAVEL"] = "TRAVEL_HD"`, then rather inefficiently performs search and replace line by line for each array element in the input file, outputting the results, which I piped to a separate outputfile.

The caveat, you'll notice, is that the search and replaces can interfere with each other, the 2nd line of output being a perfect example since the first replacement happens.  You can try ordering your replacements differently, or use a regex instead of a gsub.  I'm not certain if awk arrays are guaranteed to have a certain order, though.  Something to get you started, anyway.

2nd caveat.  There's a way to do the gsub for the whole file as the 2nd step of your BEGIN and probably make this much faster, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Great one liner, but the format of fromto is more or less fixed. There are quotes used, because of strings with space, example "DISCOVERY CHANNEL".

Comment: @Adrian - Ah, I think that can be solved with `patsplit()` and something like from here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content but we're approaching a reasonable limit on one-liners (and my skill with awk), I think :)

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this oneshot you have to use variables within a script

maybe something like below sed command for full replacement

```
-bash-4.4$ cat > toto.txt
1
2
3
-bash-4.4$ cat > titi.txt
a
b
c
-bash-4.4$ sed 's|^\s*\(\S*\)\s*\(.*\)$|/^\2\\>/s//\1/|' toto.txt | sed -f - titi.txt > toto.txt
-bash-4.4$ cat toto.txt
a
b
c
-bash-4.4$
```